# Site returns 404 when using URL without a specific page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

When I send a get request to my main URL (http://www.asospricecompare.com/) I get 404 response code - but still get all the source code.
This happens also in the browser - the site is loading but show 404 when I check it on the console -> network

[image]

But when I send the request to http://www.asospricecompare.com/home.jsp everything looks fine - I get a response code 200.

I'm using java JSP with servlet running on tomcat8.5.

I can't figure out what could be the problem.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Which page is set as the default page while loading the website?

Comment: How do I set a default page?

Comment: your default page should be default.html/default.jsp or index.html/index.jsp, if you dont wanna configure default page from htaccess

Comment: @Dan, If my answer provided you the solution, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Please try setting welcome page in web.xml to the page you want to display as a default page.